# Create nested json in postgresql

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, nested

I'm trying to create JSON object by passing to `json_object()` two arrays. One with keys, second with JSON(or JSONB) objects. So as to put JSON as value for predefined key.
The signature of `json_object()` function is `json_object(varchar[], varchar[])` but in my case I have `json_object(varchar[], json[])`. The issue is when I'm typecasting `json_object(varchar[], json[]::varchar[])` stringification creates escaped string for json element and postgress does not recognize value as nested JSON, but instead thinks that is string value.

```
SELECT
   json_object(
                ARRAY[set_of_keys::varchar],
                ARRAY[set_of_values::json],
              ) as some_column
```

gives error `function json_object(varchar[], json[]) does not exist`

```
SELECT
   json_object(
                ARRAY[set_of_keys::varchar],
                ARRAY[set_of_values::json]::varchar[],
              ) as some_column
```

lead to esacaped stringification of `set_of_values`.

How to put these objects as a value without stringification?

Sample data:

```
SELECT
   json_object(
                ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'],
                ARRAY['{"key1":"value1"}'::json, '{"key2": "value2"}'::json, '{"key3": "value3", "key4":"value4"}'::json]::varchar[]
              )
```

I would like to get rid of `::varchar[]` typecasting at the end of second array.

Comment: Because `ARRAY` is a Postgres array not a JSON array. See [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) section *8.14.1. JSON Input and Output Syntax* and [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) *Table 9.46. JSON Creation Functions*. Be aware that there are two JSON types, `json` and `jsonb`.

Comment: there is no JSON arrays at all. There are two Postgres arrays of keys and values. difference in JSON and JSONB is not significant here

Comment: Yeah, I was not playing close enough attention.  So: 1) What are you trying to achieve? An example of the input data and what the desired output is would be helpful. I'm guessing there is a better way to get to the result you want. 2) Your title says `jsonb` the code is for `json_object` which produces `json` type.

Comment: I'm trying to put json or jsonb object as a value for given set of keys. For that purpose there is no difference in the behavior of json or jsonb objects

Comment: Understood, I'm just suggesting that make the title match the code to reduce confusion on what you are trying to do. To get an answer it would help to have the sample data.  Right now ` ARRAY[set_of_values::json]::varchar[],` is taking a Postgres `ARRAY` of `json` values and turning it into a Postgres `varchar` `ARRAY` which is why you are getting the escaped stringification.

Comment: What are the values of `set_of_keys` and `set_of_values`? Please make a [mcve] that we  could e.g. paste into https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation of `json_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) says:

> All values are converted to JSON strings.

So don't use `json_object` if you want values that are arbitrary JSON values, not strings.

Instead, use [`json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT json_object_agg(key, value)
FROM UNNEST(array_of_keys, array_of_values) AS kv(key, value)
```

<sup>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=38f01c1a432bd4300fcde2824e640e6a) with your sample data)</sup>